# Conditional statement when dealing with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is write the conditional for the boolean value of my buttons. I have 4 buttons, 3 false and one true. I want a block of code to execute for the false values, and another to execute for the true value.

This is what I have so far.

```
function startGame() {
    
quiz.innerHTML = "<h1>Choose the tag that corresponds with <br> the definition of an empty        tag</h1>";
startBtn.innerHTML = "";

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "The p tag";
questionBtn.appendChild(button);
button.setAttribute("style", "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 100px;")

var button2 = document.createElement("button");
button2.textContent = "The nav tag";
questionBtn.appendChild(button2);
button2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 100px;")

var button3 = document.createElement("button");
button3.textContent = "The img tag";
questionBtn.appendChild(button3);
button3.setAttribute("style", "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 100px;")

var button4 = document.createElement("button");
button4.textContent = "The h1 tag";
questionBtn.appendChild(button4);
button4.setAttribute("style", "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 100px;")


var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button")

for (i of btns) {
    i.addEventListener("click", function() {

var button = false;
var button2 = false;
var button3 = true;
var button4 = false;

if (i === true) {
    prompt("hello")
} else { 
    alert("hello")
}
    });
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to target the the button3 with the true value. Currently, every button is returning the alert.

Comment: `i` is never true (`===`), thus the `else` always runs. Instead of using the loop for your event listeners, use `button.addEventListener()`, `button2.addEventListener()`, etc. That way you can make each do what you want individually.

Comment: If I did it that way though, wouldn't I have a multitude of unnecessary event listeners at the bottom of my code, for each button, of each question? (assuming its not always the same button that === true).

Comment: You already have instance variables for each button. You could just use them since you have them. Once you get your code to function, come back to clean it up if you prefer. Dont worry about code efficiency too much (at this stage). Get it to work.

Comment: The purpose here is to have working code that is cleaned up. I wouldn't stress so much but I only have the weekend to get it done.  I understand the fundamentals, but am trying to understand how a for loop would be incorporated in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an index to target the special element.

```js
let idx = 2; // 3rd button
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) 
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (i === idx) prompt('hello');
        else alert('hello');
    });
```

Comment: If I did as such, I wouldn't need to reference any Boolean, correct? What if I did want to reference the Boolean, would you know how to do as such using a for loop?

Comment: @Dialectics Yes, you wouldn't need four boolean variables. Is there a reason you need to do so? That makes it more complicated.

Comment: I may not need to, if I can make an if/else statement with what you've said there (the correct answer needs to continue on to the next with a "right answer" content, while false needs to remove time from the timer/give a "wrong answer" content/still move to next question. I'm only a month into class so I'm probably nowhere near as competent with understanding what I do or don't need as compared to you. I'm going to attempt it the way you have it written there.

Comment: Went with your answer. The simplest one that works wonderfully with what I am doing. Thank you.. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you delegate and use data attributes your quiz will be much simpler

```js
// this has to be AFTER the elements OR in a load event handler (see other answer below)
const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
const startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
const questionBtn = document.getElementById("questionBtn");

function startGame() {

  quiz.innerHTML = "<h1>Choose the tag that corresponds with <br> the definition of an empty        tag</h1>";
  startBtn.hiddden = true; // hide the button

  var button1 = document.createElement("button");
  button1.textContent = "The p tag";
  button1.classList.add('answer')
  button1.dataset.correct = "0"; // incorrect
  questionBtn.appendChild(button1);


  var button2 = document.createElement("button");
  button2.textContent = "The nav tag";
  button2.classList.add('answer')
  button2.dataset.correct = "0"; // incorrect
  questionBtn.appendChild(button2);

  var button3 = document.createElement("button");
  button3.textContent = "The img tag";
  button3.classList.add('answer')
  button3.dataset.correct = "1"; // correct
  questionBtn.appendChild(button3);

  var button4 = document.createElement("button");
  button4.textContent = "The h1 tag";
  button4.classList.add('answer')
  button4.dataset.correct = "0"; // incorrect
  questionBtn.appendChild(button4);

  // preferred
  /*
  questionBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => { // any click in the container
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // is it a button 
    if (!tgt) return; // not a button
    const correct = tgt.dataset.correct === "1";
    alert(`${tgt.textContent} is ${correct?"correct":"incorrect"}`)
  });
  */
  
  // using a loop instead
  questionBtn.querySelectorAll('button')
    .forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", (e) => { // a click on a buttom
      const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // is it a button 
      if (!tgt) return; // not a button
      const correct = tgt.dataset.correct === "1";
      alert(`${tgt.textContent} is ${correct?"correct":"incorrect"}`)
    })
  );
  

}

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame)
```

```css
button.answer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="quiz"></div>
<div id="questionBtn"></div>
<button type="button" id="startBtn">Start</button>
```

This is a more complex version written before I realised you need something simple

If you delegate and use an object array, your quiz will be much simpler

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let cnt = 0;
  const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const buttons = quiz.querySelectorAll('button');
  const title = quiz.querySelector('h1');
  quiz.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('button');
    tgt.classList.toggle('correct',tgt.dataset.idx === questions[cnt].correct)
    tgt.classList.toggle('incorrect',tgt.dataset.idx !== questions[cnt].correct)
  })
  const startQuiz = () => {
    if (cnt >= questions.length) return;
    const question = questions[cnt];
    title.innerHTML = question.title;
    question.answers.forEach((answer, i) => {
      buttons[i].textContent = answer;
      buttons[i].dataset.idx = i;
      buttons[i].className = "answer default"; 
    });
  }
  document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', () => {
    cnt++;
    startQuiz();
  })
  startQuiz()

});
```

```css
#quiz h1 { height: 100px; }
button.answer {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height:50px;
}

button#next {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
.default { background-color: black;}
.correct { background-color: green;} 
.incorrect { background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="quiz">
  <h1></h1><hr/>
  <button class="answer"></button>
  <button class="answer"></button>
  <button class="answer"></button>
  <button class="answer"></button>
</div>
<hr />
<button id="next">Next</button>

<script>
// this could be an separate external script

const questions = [
  {
    "title": "Choose the tag that corresponds with the definition of an empty or void tag",
    "answers": ["The p tag", "The nav tag", "The img tag", "The h1 tag"],
    "correct": "2"
  },
  {
    "title": "Which tag is used to create a hyperlink?",
    "answers": ["The li tag", "The link tag", "The ul tag", "The a tag"],
    "correct": "3"
  },
  {
    "title": "What does the 'h' stand for in 'h1', 'h2', etc.?",
    "answers": ["Header", "Horizontal", "Height", "Hyperlink"],
    "correct": "0"
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: For now, I have to stay within the scope of material we've actually learnt thus far, as this is for class. (for loops, conditionals, query selectors, get element by id, event listeners, the basics etc). Though that seems fairly interesting.

Comment: @Dialectics See updated answer. It is still using delegation because it makes sense

Comment: We haven't covered delegation in this module, so I'm not sure I can really use it. Were doing it in the present module (event delegation), so I can only stay within the scope of last weeks module sadly.

Comment: @Dialectics The code is quite similar, I added the loop for you

Answer (score 0):

you can set attribute to button and then compare it in evenlistener callback.

```
   function startGame() {
    quiz.innerHTML =
      "<h1>Choose the tag that corresponds with <br> the definition of an 
      empty        tag</h1>";
    // startBtn.innerHTML = "";

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = "The p tag";
    questionBtn.appendChild(button);
    button.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 
     100px;"
    );
    button.setAttribute("is-correct", "false");

    var button2 = document.createElement("button");
    button2.textContent = "The nav tag";
    questionBtn.appendChild(button2);
    button2.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 
       100px;"
    );
    button2.setAttribute("is-correct", "false");

    var button3 = document.createElement("button");
    button3.textContent = "The img tag";
    questionBtn.appendChild(button3);
    button3.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 
    100px;"
    );
    button3.setAttribute("is-correct", "true");

    var button4 = document.createElement("button");
    button4.textContent = "The h1 tag";
    questionBtn.appendChild(button4);
    button4.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 20px; width: 
100px;"
    );
    button4.setAttribute("is-correct", "false");

    var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");

    for (let btn of btns) {
      btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.getAttribute("is-correct") === "true") {
          alert("true");
        } else {
          alert("false");
        }
      });
    }
  }
  startGame();
```

I understand that you need the code to be easy, but there are some things done wrong way. For example, instead of setting style to element, create a class in your CSS, paste the style you want to apply and then just add a class to element with "element.classList.add("class")".
Also, if you want to create several buttons which are the same, don't create a special variable for each button, but use an array instead with values that are individual for each button (or, array of objects, if there are more individual values for each button) and than loop through it.

Comment: Please use data-attributes instead of custom attributes!

Comment: @mplungjan It is working well with custom attributes, but thanks for advice. Should I edit my answer?

Comment: Feel free to do so. It is [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)